# Apache22 displays PHP source

Tags: php, apache-2.2, freebsd

I've just install Apache22, PHP 5 with Apache module, and MySQL.  The Apache conf file has the PHP LoadModule line, but it still displays the PHP source code.  Are there any other reasons why this happens?

Comment: anything in the error log?

Answer (score 2):

One common reason is that you are using the PHP short open tag `<?` but PHP has [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) disabled.

Comment: That's true, but I'm not using short tags.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may need to set an application type, so it knows to use the php module based on a file extension or something.

I don't use FreeBSD, so I don't know the installation process. On Windows and Ubuntu/Linux Mint this is done automatically.

This is what I have in a file called php5.conf (that's just how it's organized in Ubuntu), but this can be just put in your http.conf anywhere after your load module line.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    # To re-enable php in user directories comment the following lines
    # (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
    # prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        <Directory /home/*/public_html>
            php_admin_value engine Off
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to add a line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

in httpd.conf.
The most correct solution is described in the response of Gohn67.